# Connecting an already existing database in Android

Tags: android

What is the best way to Connect an external database in my android application and retreive data from it? i am trying to develop a simple Quiz application where the questions and their options should be retreived from database. i have created the database using SQLite Browser.
I have seen lot of tutorials which tells how to create database and use it in android. But i couldnot find any tutorial which teaches me how to retreive from already created database.

Comment: Do you have database on external server?

Comment: If you search for "ship database with android app" you can find useful resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

If you are going to connect to a pre-created and prefilled database then you should embed that SQLite Database file in your APK and connect it and proceed like you’ve seen in tutorials. have a look at [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

And if you want to retrieve data from a database exists on a remote machine then you have to expose data using one of web service technologies (for instance, XML Web Services) and consume it in your Android App.